# get text between 2 string start with wordlist and ended with puntuation list in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to take a sentence between 2 strings start with my word list
 Ended with `/. or /? or /, or /!

The code that i have tried

```
def sumar():
    START = open('F:\\Skripsi\\source code\\katadata.txt', 'r' )
    END = "\.|\?"
    test = text1.get(0.0, END)
    m = re.compile('(%s)(.*?)%s' % (START.read ().replace('\n','|'), END), flags = re.IGNORECASE)
    smr = m.search(test).group(2)
    se = text2.insert(END, smr)

    text1= Text(root, width=50,height=30)
    text1.pack(side=LEFT)
    text2 = Text(root, width=80, height=30)
    text2.pack(side=LEFT)
    btn5= Button(root, text= "SUMMARY", command=sumar)
    btn5.pack(side=TOP)
```

but, when i run it, it's error like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)  
File "F:\Skripsi\source code\modul-token.py", line 84, in sumar
    test = text1.get(0.0, END)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3074, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', index1, index2)
TclError: bad text index "\."
```

can anyone help me? thak you

Answer (score 1):

You have redefined the Tk-Constant `END` with `END = "\.|\?"`.
Rename your `END` to e.g. `RE_END`.

Comment: ok, thak you, it works 
but know it got error like this

'Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:\Skripsi\source code\modul-token.py", line 86, in sumar
    smr = m.search(test).group(2)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' '
 
do you know what is the problem

Comment: This is another question. Simple answer: The search pattern is not found.

Comment: yeah, you are right. 
do you know how to get it?
thanks

Comment: **hello, my name is lionel messi from football club of Barcelona. I want to ask you where do you live?**

(start) my word list : want to ask, (end) /. | /?
so, i just want to take  sentence : where do you live